# Cards tab layout and navigation between tabs with buttons and tabs

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

The following example in the fiddle illustrates a form with a layout of card tabs.

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1sp6

**Problem**:

If I navigate between the tabs / cards with the buttons works fine; however if I simultaneously navigate by selecting / click the tabs, I can not get a synchronization between the tabs and the previous / next buttons.

**Hypothesis 1**: is there any way to do this navigation in sync?

**Hypothesis 2**: deactivate the possibility of triggering the click event or tabchange in the tabs so that it is only possible to navigate between tabs with the buttons. How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hypothesis 2:

Add the following listener to your tabpanel:

```
beforetabchange: function(){
   return false;
}
```

And in your button listeners, around the `this.doCardNavigation`:

```
 this.suspendEvents();
 this.doCardNavigation(1);
 this.resumeEvents(true);
```

This will prevent tab clicks from changing the active tab, but allow the next/previous buttons to do so. Returning `false` from the before listener will cancel the event. `suspendEvents` will prevent the before listener from being reached, thus allowing the tab change.

Hypothesis 1 is also possible - You could create a variable to store your current selected tab and update it and corresponding views as tabs are changed. This would be much simpler with a [view model](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.2/guides/application_architecture/view_models_data_binding.html), as you could bind formulas to the buttons disabled config.

Comment: Thanks Jaimee. The hypothesis 1 works well. I'll try also with formulas